# Previewing/changing image from input to img tag don't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

just gonna ask something,
my jquery code don't work in safari browser in terms of changing the image source from input type "file". here is my code, please I need this, thanks for answering.

```
$(window).ready(function(){
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#prev').attr('src', e.target.result);
             if($('#prev').width() >= 350){
                $('#prev').attr('style', 'width: 100%;');
             }else{
                $('#prev').attr('style', 'width: auto;');
             }
             if($('#prev').height() >= 210){
                $('#prev').attr('style', 'height: 210px;');
             }else{

             }
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    }
};
$("#seeimg").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
});
```